# Creation of a non-maximally entangled photon state

Tags: quantum-entanglement

I'm reading a paper on testing the Bell Eberhard Inequality.
The experiment performs polarization tests on states of the following form:
$|\Psi_r>=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+r^2}}(|HV>+r|VH>)$,
where $H$ stands for horizontally polarized and $V$ stands for vertically polarized.

They say they can choose r by the use of $\lambda/2$ and $\lambda/4$ plates on an entangled photon state.

How is that possible?

Comment: You don't have to worry about the 1/sqrt(1+r^2) out front, because that just comes from normalization. They are just saying that they can choose the amount of |VH> relative to |HV> using half- and quarter-wave plates.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not there yet. (still writing, acc. hit enter)

Comment: I just got it, i think. A lambda/2 plate rotates the polarization by 2alpha. We put the lambda/2 plate in one ray so that the polarization rotates a little from an even H, V to more H and less V. Right?